# Failed to convert value of type java.util.Date to String

Tags: android, timestamp, google-cloud-firestore, java.util.date

I'm creating an app for membership registration I  stored uesr information into firestore .My all data is saved into firestore as a string and except join_date it is save as TimeStamp.
But When I'm retrieving those data its show me this error

> Failed to convert value of type java.util.Date to String

I'm using this code for saving current date(join_date)

```
members.put("join_date", FieldValue.serverTimestamp());
```

and I'm retrieving this data as a string in my adapter

```
holder.mjoinDate.setText(mClip.get(position).getJoin_date());
```

Comment: Can you please post the full code of retrieving data from firestore?

Comment: There's not enough relevant code here to see what's going wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to set Date Object in your text field. Please try as follows

Example:

```
String convertedString = convertDateToString(mClip.get(position).getJoin_date());
holder.mjoinDate.setText(convertedString);


private String convertDateToString (Date date) {
    //change according to your supported formate 
    DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss");
    return dateFormat.format(date);
}
```